# Access violation with ZeroMQ 3.2.5 in a mailbox_t::recv

Tags: c++, zeromq

I am getting this error while using ZeroMQ version 3.2.5:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCCA9395FC (KERNELBASE.dll) in [OURPROCESS].dmp: 0x40000015:  %hs (parameters: 0x00000000522694C0).

libzmq.dll!zmq::mailbox_t::recv(zmq::command_t * cmd_, int timeout_) Line 86    C++
libzmq.dll!zmq::socket_base_t::process_commands(int timeout_, bool throttle_) Line 855  C++
libzmq.dll!zmq::socket_base_t::getsockopt(int option_, void * optval_, unsigned __int64 * optvallen_) Line 291  C++
libzmq.dll!zmq_poll(zmq_pollitem_t * items_, int nitems_, long timeout_) Line 892   C++
[OURPROCESS]::QPoller::Poll(__int64 timeout) Line 63    C++
```

This happens persistently only in one machine that this process is used. However no specific pattern could be detected. The Windows version used is Server 2012 R2.

Do you have any idea why this could be happening ? The only thing that comes to mind is that maybe that machine is out of sockets. However after investigating the machine with netstat this seems unlikely.

Comment: Without code it is hard to say.  Most 0MQ sockets are not thread safe, check that you aren't sharing a socket between threads.  Messages are sent asynchronously, so be careful to not deallocate a message before it is dispatched.

Comment: Missing all information what preceded a call on **Line 63** in your post. **Would you mind to read about how to ask the MCVE-based questions** ? StackOverflow encourages users to present a **M**inimum ( efficiency ) + **C**omplete ( self-contained ) + **V**erifiable ( ready for re-runs ) + **E**xamples ( a full example, with all details so as to allow for re-testing ) of code, that you struggle to make working. The best next step is to learn about this Community practice + revise & complete your MCVE above. Anyway, welcome in this great Community of Knowledge & become our contributing member.

Comment: Thanks for the information user3666197. I will check it out for future posts !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused most likely because of another process claiming the port 5905 that 0mq uses in version 3.

https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/1542